# For loop not running through length

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal, converters

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong that is causing my for loop to not go through my length. I am trying to use a user input to convert a Binary to a Decimal, but its not working. What I have is

**Edited**

```js
var val = $("txtIn").value;
if (cT[1].checked) {
  var bVal = val;
  if (isNaN(bVal)) {
    alert(val + " is not a number. A number is required to run the program.");
  } else if ((val % 1) !== 0) {
    alert(val + " is not an integer. A whole number is required to run the program.");
  } else if (bVal < 0) {
    alert(val + " is not able to convert. Input must be positive integer.");
  } else {
    convertByArrayB(bVal);
  }
  }
  
  function convertByArrayB(bVal) {
    var r, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < bVal.length; i++) {
      r = bVal.charAt(i);
      if (r !== '1' && r !== '0') {
        alert("You did not enter a valid binary number. Please try again!");
      }

      var nv = parseInt(r, 2);
      
    }

    $("txtOut").value = nv;

  }
```

I don't think you need the top portion, but better safe than sorry. Thank you in advance for any help. (Love this community BTW)

Comment: Please fix your code. You can't have newlines in JavaScript strings.

Comment: You're reassigning `bVal = nv` inside the loop.

Comment: After that, `bVal.length` is undefined.

Comment: Your braces aren't balanced. There's no `}` for the first `if`.

Comment: What is `r[i]` supposed to be? `r` is the current character of `bVal`.

Comment: Thank you! I had thought that i needed to run the parseInt binary formula going off of the place it was, but I guess is r = bVal.charat(i) it doesn't need that.

Comment: So I removed the [i], and the bval = nv; and now it is running through the length, but not adding up the 1's and 0's to show the the decimal. When I input 101, it returned 1. (I'll edit the code above to reflect what I did)

Comment: Don't remove the original code, add your new code at the end.

Comment: Is there supposed to be an array used in `convertByArrayB`?

Comment: the decimal to binary function was an array, but the binary to decimal did not need to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing `bVal` inside the loop when you do:

```
bVal = nv;
```

so the value of `bVal.length` is `undefined` on the next iteration, and the loop stops.

The code that calls `parseInt()` should be *after* the loop, not inside it. There's no need to reassign `bVal`, and it should parse `bVal`, not `r[i]`.

```js
function convertByArrayB(bVal) {
  var r, i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < bVal.length; i++) {
    r = bVal.charAt(i);
    if (r !== '1' && r !== '0') {
      alert("You did not enter a valid binary number. Please try again!");
      return;
    }
  }
  var nv = parseInt(bVal, 2);

  document.getElementById("txtOut").value = nv;

}

convertByArrayB("101");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Result: <input id="txtOut">
```

Comment: OMG Thank you! So basically I was confusing it, and also had my formula in the wrong place. Thank you again Barmar! You are the best!